# How to set stroke for switch thumb without xml on Android?

Tags: android

I have customized the switch with xml and I want it to change color to the user's liking. But when you do that, the stroke of the thumb will disappear. How to have it without xml?

```
switch2.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(getColor("system_accent1_300"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
switch2.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(getColor("system_accent1_100"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be helpful to see the xml code for your custom switch. Also, please check out [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help properly formatting the code in your question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/0wuh9II18_o